# Excel VBA - Highlight Selected Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to highlight the selected cell and it works fine. However, I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it without using `On error resume next`.

Also, If I use this statement does that mean other errors in the same event or procedures called by the event would not be catched?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("range_name"), Me.Range("range_name2"), _
Me.Range("range_name3"))) Is Nothing Then
Static xLastRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
xLastRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
Set xLastRng = Target
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the goal of this sub to highlight the selected cell if it intersects with the 3 ranges and is not blank?

Comment: I assume it will only error on the first selection, since `xLastRng` is nothing, so test it: `If Not xLastRng is Nothing then xLastRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

Comment: my goal is to highlight the selected cell in any of those three ranges and de-highlight the previously selected cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach, because right now you are inputing a fill color instead of conditional formatting. You might ruin other cells their format doing so.

What I done is for example use this conditional formatting rule on column C, D and E (you have other ranges so use them accordingly).

```
=AND(ROW()=CELL("ROW"),COLUMN()=CELL("COLUMN"))
```

This alone should do the trick, but it's some kind of glitch (too fast) for the screen to properly update the selected cell with a conditional format. Scrolling down and back up fixes this and you will see that the selected cell is formatted if it is within your ranges.

To counter this I used a forced waiting time on a selection change in the worksheet untill Excel is done calculating...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

No you will notice that it will not glitch out :)

[image]

If the glitch doesn't happen on your side, you can leave out the VBA part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static xLastRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("range_name"), _
                                                  Me.Range("range_name2"), _
                                                  Me.Range("range_name3")))
    'clear previous range hilite first, since overlap
    '  between previous & new could occur
    If Not xLastRange Is Nothing Then 
        xLastRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        Set xLastRange = Nothing
    End If

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Set xLastRange = rng
    End If 
End Sub
```

It's unclear from your question whether you'd want to clear any previous highlighting if a new selection falls outside of your checked ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one!!

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RowLiner.htm

[image]

Simply point to the Excel AddIn and run it.

https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/